# Reading from a file indicated by a file

Tags: c

I'm trying to do a program that opens files in a directory that are included in another.
Simply put:
Open file -> Read which files to open -> open and show their contents.

Here's the directory:

```
-rwxrwx--- btag_test.c
-rwxrwx--- file.txt
drwxrwxr-x samples
```

The "file.txt" is just a list of files to open:

```
sample0001.mp3
sample0002.mp3
etc.
```

I'm trying to get their hexdump in plaintext to get header with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void show(char *filename) {
    char aux[60] = "sample/";
    strcat(aux, filename);
    printf(">>>>%s>>>>\n", aux);
    FILE *ptf = fopen(aux, "rb");
    unsigned long long byte;
    while (byte=fgetc(ptf) != EOF) {
        printf("%llx",byte);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (f==NULL) printf("Erro");
    else printf("OK");

    char tmp[50];
    char files[1000][50];
    int i=0;
    while( fscanf(f, "%s", tmp) == 1) {
        printf("%s\n", tmp);
        strcpy(files[i++], tmp);
    } 
    printf(">>%s\n", files[3]);
    show(files[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not being able to open file, since I get a "core dumped" message everytime. I'm assuming it's because I'm not really opening the file.

The usage is:

```
./a.out file.txt
```

I know the program is relatively stupid, but my goal is to later analyse the output of thing with fseek to get it's header - but I have to open the damned thing first...

**Would appreciate help with this and pointers on how to extract a string of bytes within a certain offset with fseek after opening the file.**

Comment: `while (byte=fgetc(ptf) != EOF) {` <<-- Ouch!

Comment: @user3629249 thank you! Still out puts that file wasn't found :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding:

```
unsigned long long byte; 
while (byte=fgetc(ptf) != EOF) {
```

the type returned from `fgetc()` is `int`, not `unsigned long long`.

after:

```
FILE *ptf = fopen(aux, "rb");
```

should be:

```
if( ! ptf ) 
{ 
    perror( "fopen failed" ); 
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); 
}
```

which will output both the `fopen failed` message and the text reason the system thinks the failure occurred to `stderr`

regarding:

```
while( fscanf(f, "%s", tmp) == 1) {
```

since `tmp[]` is 50 characters long and the `%s` always appends a NUL byte to the input, if the line in the file is greater than 49 characters, a buffer overflow will occur, result in undefined behavior.

Suggest:

```
while( fscanf(f, "%49s", tmp) == 1) {
```

regarding:

```
while (byte=fgetc(ptf) != EOF) {
```

since `byte` is unsigned, it will NEVER recognize `EOF` (which is usually -1). Also, the statement is missing a needed set of parens.

Suggest:

```
while ( (byte=fgetc(ptf)) != EOF) {
```

so the assignment is performed before the comparison. Your compiler should have told you about this problem.

regarding:

```
if (f==NULL) printf("Erro");
```

1. please, only one statement per line.
2. error messages are to be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.
3. since the call to `fopen()` failed, should exit the program.

Suggest:

```
if (f==NULL) 
{ 
    perror( "fopen for the list of files to display failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); 
}
```

Note: exit the program on failure. DO not try to read from the file when the call to `fopen()` failed.

regarding:

```
drwxrwxr-x samples
```

and

```
char aux[60] = "sample/";
```

Notice the different spelling? So you are not going to be able to open any of the files with that spelling error.

for safety, this statement:

```
while( fscanf(f, "%s", tmp) == 1) {
```

should be:

```
while( i<1000 && fscanf(f, "%49s", tmp) == 1) {
```

Note the check for too many files and the limit of each filename to be less than 50.

regarding:

```
printf(">>%s\n", files[3]); 
show(files[3]);
```

What about when the number of files is less than 4? (remembering that array indexes start at 0).

regarding:

```
while (byte=fgetc(ptf) != EOF) 
{
    printf("%llx",byte);
```

the code is only reading 1 8bit char at a time, not a `unsigned long long`.

when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  for `gcc`, at a minimum use:

```
-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11
```

Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: Thank you! It opened after making the changes especially the "samples" one!